# Создание страницы и ссылки для добавленной статьи

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Создал себе блог. Все окей. Осталось только одно - "Читать дальше".

Хочу при нажатии на ссылку открылась новая страница со всей статьей и со ссылкой. Как бы прикрепить ссылку к этой записи и при вводе ссылки открылась эта страница.

Но не знаю как сделать это. Какой механизм. Поискал в интернете, но все еще темно для меня! Буду рад вашей помощи!

**UPDATE**

У меня есть панель управления, откуда я могу добавлять статьи. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии "Опубликовать", генерировалась ссылка для данной статьи. А затем, при нажатии на "Читать далее" осуществлялся переход по выше генерированной ссылке, открылась новая страница с полной статьей и с той же самой ссылкой в адресной строке. Ну как это в обычных сайтах делается. Надеюсь смог объясниться.

Comment: Вот именно, "осталось только одно - читать дальше". На ваш вопрос может быть очень пространный ответ, потому что и вопрос пространный.

Comment: @navi1893, Перефразируйте, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос: исправьте грамматические ошибки, правильно расставьте запятые. Если ещё добавите побольше уточняющей информации, то Вы ускорите получение ответа.

Comment: Ссылка делается так:

    <a href="адрес_статьи">Читать дальше</a>

Вы это хотели узнать? Это HTML, а не PHP и MySQL

Comment: Смешно :) я не это говорю. Я ведь отметил тэгом пхп, а не хтмл. У меня есть панель управления, откуда я могу добавлять статьи. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии "Опубликовать", генерировалась ссылка для данной статьи. А затем, при нажатии на "Читать далее" осуществлялся переход по выше генерированной ссылке, открылась новая страница с полной статьей и с той же самой ссылкой в адресной строке. Ну как это в обычных сайтах делается. Надеюсь смог объясниться.

Comment: @navi1893, в обычных сайтах ссылки не генерируются. Ссылка всегда одна - `/необязательный-префикс/параметры/необязательный-суффикс`, например, `/articles/число`. Просто при переходе по такой ссылке определяется, существует ли определяемая такими параметрами запись в базе данных, и если ее нет, выводится 404.

Comment: А как сделать это условие, что если данная ссылка есть в БД, то открыть, если нет, то вывести эррор. Я искал в инете, но не нашел ничего.

Comment: @navi1893, не хранятся никакие ссылки в БД. В БД хранятся материалы, ссылки на них ссылаются. Просто достаете по айдишнику запись, если запрос вернул пустоту, то ее и не существует.

Comment: @navi1893 блин, да серьезно что ли?

    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // /articles/12345
    $bits = explode('/', $uri);
    $id = intval(array_pop($bits));
    if ($id < 1) {
        error404();
    }
    $res = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = $id");
    if (!$res) {
        error404();
    }
    // дальше идет вывож валяющегося в $res

Comment: А как сделать проверку то? Допустим я ввел в адресной строке /123.php. Как запустить проверку на наличие данной записи в БД? В какой файл приписать данную проверку?

Я сделал перенаправление через htaccess на файл redirect.php. В котором я проверяю на соответствие в БД. Но как мне узнать какой адрес был записан до перенаправления?

Answer (score 3):

[@navi1893](/users/4969/navi1893), то, что вы хотите реализовать - это небольшое, но уже приложение. Придется немного уйти в абстракции, если вы хотите сделать все красиво.

#### 1. Front Controller

Первая вещь, которую мы реализуем - это общий обработчик запросов. Он должен вызываться сервером в качестве фоллбэка каждый раз, когда сервер не обнаруживает соответствующих запросу файлов (это делается, чтобы отдавать статику без лишней нагрузки и задержки).

Front controller реализуется просто как некая точка входа, которая запускает приложение. Других функций у него нет. Самый простой Front Controller будет выглядеть так:

```
<?php //index.php
include __DIR__.'/bootstrap.php'; // файл, который ответственен за подгрузку класса App (реализующего приложение) и всего сопряженного
$app = new App;
$app->run();
```

Сервер загружает index.php, index.php загружает приложение, все счастливы.

#### 2. App (приложение)

Приложение - это такая супер-сущность, которая ничего не делает, кроме как содержит информацию о приложении (имя, версия, текущий роут) и управляет другими сущностями (объектами). В нашем СуперПростомПриложении класс App может быть реализован следующим образом:

```
class App
{
    /**
     * __construct - это конструктор, который всегда вызывается
     * при создании класса. Можно быть уверенным, что написанный
     * здесь код вызовется автоматически (и именно поэтому я пишу
     * его здесь).
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->loadComponents();
        $this->router = new Router;
        $this->route = $this->router->parse($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        // функция, которая тем или иным образом запускает нужный модуль
        $this->runController($this->route);
    }
    /**
     * Эта функция просто отвечает за подгрузку дополнительных
     * сущностей, внутри у нее может быть что угодно.
     */
    public function loadComponents()
    {
        include_once __DIR__.'/router.php';
    }
    /**
     * Функция для отображения ошибки 404
     */
    public staticfunction throw404()
    {
        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 404 Page Not Found');
        echo '<h1>Aw crap, the page does not exist!</h1>';
        die;
    }
}
```

#### 3. Router

Третья часть, которую нужно реализовать - это роутер. Роутер ответственен за то, чтобы каким-то образом преобразовать полученный запрос в понятный для приложения формат о том, какой именно запрос поступил. В уже классической схеме MVC роутер получает на вход тип запроса и адрес запроса, а на выход выдает контроллер, ответственный за обработку такого запроса и варьируемые параметры запроса. В нашем простом случае можно сделать так:

```
class Router
{
    public $rules = array( // таблица правил
        'post/(\d+)' => 'post/show',
        'post/new' => 'post/form',
        'post/(\d+)/edit' => 'post/edit',
        // и так далее
    );
    public function route($uri)
    {
        foreach ($this->rules as $rule => $route) {
            if (preg_match('~^'.$rule.'$~', $uri, $m) { // сравнение текущего адреса и правила
                array_shift($m); // первый элемент массива - полное совпадение, оно нам не нужно
                return array( // нашел совпадение - верни
                    'route' => $route,
                    'params' => $m,
                );
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

#### 4. Контроллер

В этой секции надо описать сам вызов того кода, который ответственен за отображение поста. В MVC принято, что контроллер - это класс с методами-действиями, роутер в своем выводе указывает на такое действие, и приложению остается просто вызвать то, что предложил роутер. Но, строго говоря, это необязательно класс или вообще какая-то языковая конструкция - роутер может указывать на файлы, которые требуется подключать, или сразу возвращать анонимные функции (привет, laravel). Просто по схеме MVC работает большинство фреймворков и я опишу типичный контроллер.

```
class PostController
{
    public function show($id)
    {
        $id = intval($id);
        // сейчас неважно, что такое $db и откуда оно взялось. Это
        // просто соединение с базой данных, которое возвращает пост
        // (если он существует)
        $post = $db->select()->from('posts')->where('id = '.$id)->execute();
        if (!$post) {
            App::throw404();
        }
        // организуем вывод через подключение простого шаблона
        include BASEDIR.'/views/post.php';
    }
}
```

#### Все вместе (application flow)

1. Front controller получает запрос
2. Вызывается приложение
3. Приложение подгружает компоненты, в т.ч. роутер
4. Роутеру скармливается детали текущего запроса, в ответ на что роутер отвечает, что именно нужно вызвать дальше
5. Приложение вызвает этот код (контроллер)
6. Код (контроллер) проверяет данные запроса и убеждается, что пост существует или выдает ошибку 404
7. Код (контроллер) осуществляет вывод данных

#### Фу, это все сложно, мне б халявы

1. Добавляем тем или иным способом пост в базу данных
2. Делаем файл post.php
3. В post.php ловим GET-параметр `id`:

```
<?php
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? intval($_GET['id']) : 0;
if ($id < 1) { // неверный ввод, кто-то дурачится
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 404 Page Not Found');
    echo '<h1>Aw crap, the page does not exist!</h1>';
    die;
}
```

4. Проверяем существование такого поста:

```
$link = mysqli_connect(/* параметры */);
$post = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = '.$id);
if (!$post) {
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 404 Page Not Found');
    echo '<h1>Aw crap, the page does not exist!</h1>';
    die;
}
```

5. К этой точке в скрипт пост совершенно точно существует и все его данные содержатся в переменной $post. Выводим, что хотим.
6. Когда надо дать ссылку на пост, выводим `/post.php?id=%ID поста%`.
7. Осознаем боль из-за того, что нормальные пацаны так не делают еще с 2000 года.

#### И самое последнее

На всякий случай еще раз подчеркну, что при создании поста никаких ссылок в базе не создается. Вообще никаких ссылок и файлов не создается. Где-то в приложении лежит обработчик - неважно, в каком виде, контроллер, просто файл с процедурным кодом, нас это не волнует - которого тоже не волнует (но не волнует его какие там изменения сделаны с постами). Этот обработчик в момент принятия запроса не смотрит на наличие url, а выцеляет из адреса сведения о посте и проверяет его наличие. Для него абсолютно нет разницы сколько в базе постов и что мы про эти посты думаем. Его логика проста: есть пост в базе - отобрази, нет поста в базе - верни 404.

#### Ну честно, самое-самое последнее

Настоятельно рекомендую написать микропроект на Yii или каком-нибудь Slim для того, чтобы а) перекинуть всю эту боль по организации запросов на фреймворк и б) посмотреть, как это все может работать. Проще Yii фреймворков, наверное, быть не может, Slim тоже не rocket science, насколько знаю.